# XDebug with Symfony and PhpStorm doesn't work (Ubuntu installation)

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, xdebug

***Facts about my system*
Ubuntu 15.10
Php 5.6.11
Symfony 2.7 
PhpStorm 10
xDebug 2.4**

I really struggle getting xdebug to work under my Symfony project in PhpStorm.

I installed xdebug
configured the php.ini file in my /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
and in the cli folder

> [xdebug]
>       zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so
>       xdebug.remote_enable = 1
>       xdebug.remote_port = 9000
>       xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
>       xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1

But when I "Start listening for PHP Debug Connections" and set breakpoints in my application and run tests with breakpoints in it, Xdebug just doesn't break the programm.

php -v

> PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 (cli) 
>       Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
>       Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
>       
> with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend
>       Technologies
>       
> with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

[Xdebug shows up under my PhP interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POXg0.png)

**If you need more Information please let me know
Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I solved it by putting the xdebug settings in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

Comment: if you have enough rep, you should accept your answer ... it is useful and can help others.